# How to Transfer a SystemRescueCd ISO to a USB Drive for Use on a Mac with High Sierra Installed?

Tags: bootcamp, usb, partition, startup, high-sierra

[The instructions the for SystemRescueCd software](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/Installing-SystemRescueCd-on-a-USB-stick/) does not mention how to install for use by Intel based Mac computers. I wish to boot the software from either a entire drive or a partition on a drive. I currently have High Sierra installed.

Once booted, I will be using the software to move an Windows 10 partition on a 2013 iMac.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to transfer a windows bootcamp partition from one mac to another, I suggest using the WinClone Utility. It lets you make a disk image of the bootcamp partition, then you can restore it on another machine.